# An equation in Laughlin Argument paper (1981)

Tags: electrons, electronic-band-theory, quantum-hall-effect

In his paper *[Quantized Hall conductivity in two dimensions](http://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.23.5632)*, Laughlin considers a ribbon of two-dimensional metal bent into a loop of
circumference $L$, and pierced everywhere by a magnetic
field $H_o$ normal to its surface. He says that the current through the loop is equal to the adiabatic derivative of the electronic energy $U$ of the system wrt the magnetic flux $\phi$ through the loop:
$$I=c\frac{\partial U}{\partial \phi}=\frac{c}{L}\frac{\partial U}{\partial A}$$

My question is what is the origin of this equation and why is the current equal to the adiabatic derivative of the electronic energy $U$?

Comment: I think your question might be already answered in [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47078/136928). See the comments right below the question. [Laughlin's own Nobel Lecture](https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/physics/1998/laughlin/lecture/) also has more details on this equation pp 271-272.